# How to check if variable exists for src and href otherwise use default value?

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have an image within a  tag in a handlebars email. Both src and href values are optional variables.

I want to use the `url` if it exists otherwise `default_url` AND use `image_url` if it exists otherwise `default_image_url`

What is the best way to write this in valid handlebars notation?

```
<a href={{url ? url : 'default_url'}}>
  <img src={{image_url ? image_url : 'default_image_url'}}/>
</a>
```

Comment: Do you have the ability to create your helper or modify what data is passed to this template?